# mocha async is not defined

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am using mocha to test code written in NodeJS.

The code being tested, target, uses async.

```
function target(){
    ...
    async.waterfall([...]);
}
```

When I call it from it function in

```
it('should do something', function(){
    var result = target();  
    chai.expect(newAd0.coarseloc.longitude).to.be.within(-79.01,-78.99);
})
```

mocha complains that

```
ReferenceError: async is not defined
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async` is an npm package, install the package using `npm install async`.

Add this at the top of your file:

```
var async = require('async');
```